# Maven compilation error when importing from a nested sibling module

Tags: java, maven

I am working with a multi-module Maven project and trying to import a dependent class from a module nested in one child of a parent
to a module nested in its sibling. Here is a simplified hierarchy of the project:

```
pom.xml (parent)
 |--A
    |--pom.xml
    |--C
       |--pom.xml
       |--src
 |--B
    |--pom.xml
    |--D
       |--pom.xml
       |--src
```

Here's a class within the C module:

**Dummy.java**

```
package com.xyz.A.C;

import com.xyz.B.D.DummyDependency;

public class Dummy {
   public static int callDependency(int num) {
       return dummyDependency.absoluteVal(num);
   }
}
```

Here's a class within the D module:

**DummyDependency.java**

```
package com.xyz.B.D;

public class DummyDependency {
    /**
     * Return the absolute value of a number.
     * @param num an integer
     */
     public static int absoluteVal(int num) {
         if (num > 0) {
            return num;
         } else {
            return -num;
         }
     }
 }
```

When I run `mvn clean install` I get a compilation error that resembles the following:[image]

How do I get access to the module nested in the sibling of the child module without the compilation error?

Comment: Can you share the (simplified) `pom.xml` of module `D`? does it depend on module `C`?

Comment: Seems `C` depends on `D`. But you're building `C` before `D`. You should probably change this order.

Comment: @Mureinik the pom.xml for module D contains dependencies from the sibling modules which are in module B, nothing from module C. I tried changing the build order of A and B in the parent pom.xml and the compilation error is still present.

Comment: Never rely on build order. Define an explicit dependency as Mureinik already showed.

Answer (score 3):

Don't rely on the build order. If a class in module `D` needs to use a class from module `C`, you should explicitly depend on it:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.xyz</groupId>
        <artifactId>A.C</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```